# How to connect AutoComplete feature in RelFinder

Tags: xml, flash, autocomplete, sparql

I am working on a project where we decided to use [RelFinder software](http://www.visualdataweb.org/relfinder.php).

I have been able to get it to connect to our SPARQL endpoint, and it displays our data, but I have been having trouble connecting the autocomplete feature of RelFinder, where once typing in the search boxes it will start giving autocomplete suggestions from the data. [A demo can be used here](http://www.visualdataweb.org/relfinder/relfinder.php).

What I followed was [Integrating the RelFinder](http://www.visualdataweb.org/integrating.php) to setup however, I still have not been able to connect autocomplete. I also looked at the "[Configuring the RelFinder](http://www.visualdataweb.org/configuration.php)" page, which is how I connected our data, but still having trouble with the autocomplete.

Thank you for any advice anyone may have on this.

Comment: I think you should ask such a specific question about a particular tool directly to the developers of RelFinder. Not sure if somebody here can help you, but let's see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply AKSW, I have emailed the developers, and received an out of office until November 2 from one developers email, and have had no response from the other main developers. That's why I chose to place this question here, as I need to start getting progress moving on this issue. I know it's quite specific, hopefully someone is able to kindly aid me with some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar 'issue' (actually its not an issue) and solved it by putting the string for search and display in the graph in the RDF in the `rdfs:label` section.
See in the `config/Config.xml`-file (or in the Settings) the AutocompleteURIs (standard: `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label`), where you can edit this.

For example my triple looks like this:

```
    @prefix testunit:      <http://testunit.net/> .
    @prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
    testunit:unit rdfs:label "this text will be searched and displayed" .
```

And if the AutocompleteURI is set right it should search and display "this text will be searched and displayed".